# Summing up the price of production and selling prices

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: DataModel]

1. I need to write query and calculate the total CostPrice’s and total Sellprice’s related to Material of ID=1.  I want to calculate total costs so I have to include the QuantityColumn from the table Materials right?

   ```
   SELECT SUM((CostPrice) * M.Quantity) AS 'TotalCostExclusive', SUM((SellPrice) * M.Quantity) AS 'SellPriceExclusive'
   FROM Materials AS M INNER JOIN Warehouse AS W 
   ON M.Warehouse_id = W.Id 
   WHERE M.Material_Id = '1';
   ```

   I tried this, but I'm not sure the result is equal to the required task.
2. Now I want to write new query to include the Discount on both cost and selling prices.
3. Since I’m a beginner and this data model is for student purpose, I would like to know why I must to have a table WarehouseIdentities. What exactly this table doing here and what role it has.

Comment: Please restrict your question to one question per question. Don't ask multiple distinct questions in a single question, even if they are related.

Comment: 1. Sounds right. 2. You'd need to be clearer about your schema - for example, does every item have a DiscountPercentage (even if there is no discount attributable - a 0% discount)? The answer will determine whether you use an `INNER` or `LEFT` join onto the discount table. 3. Because the schema seems poorly designed and named - `WarehouseIdentities` is equivalent in English to a collection of "Warehouses", and `Warehouse` is probably equivalent in English to something like a collection of "Warehouse Contents" or "Stock Lines".

Comment: @Donnatal:  Lets start with question #3) Your teacher's data model is very vague.  You'll need to go ask him/her what `ID` in [Warehouse] represents. Is it the `Warehouse_id` in [WarehouseIdentities]?  Or is it `ID` in [Discount]?  Both are going to link to different `ID`'s... one being the warehouse it resides in and the other being an assembled item.  It would help if you could tell us what each "link" is between each table.  Something just seems "not quite right" about this data model.  Best of luck getting info from your teacher. :)